# variable scope work in 2 if statement

Tags: php

In the second if function after request `anotherpost` `print $post` can't see anything, I read the manual and try
1. `global $post = $_REQUEST['post'];` in getpost()
or
2. pass argument `return $post` in 1st `if` to `getpost($post)`
both not work, but is it the variable scope problem?

Thanks.

```
//index.php
require 'test.php';
$test = new test();
$test->getpost();


//test.php
class test{
public function getform(){
    ....
    require 'form.php';
}

public function getpost(){
    $post = $_REQUEST['post'];
    if($_REQUEST['post']){
        print $post;
        require `form_anotherpost.php`;
    }
    if($_REQUEST['anotherpost']){
        print $post;
    }
}

//form.php
<form>
    <input type="submit" name="post" value="post">
</form>
//form_anotherpost.php
<form>
     <input type="submit" name="anotherpost" value="anotherpost">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the code to this:

```
public function getpost(){
    $post = $_REQUEST['post'];
    if($_REQUEST['post']){
        print $post;
    }
    if(1 == 1){
        print $post;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to see if your variable exists in the second if statement by knowing the statement will return true.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking, then you should use `if isset` first and then `elseif`. One you got your data processed then you can print it.

Try this:

```
public function getpost($_REQUEST) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['post'])) {
        print $_REQUEST['post'];
    }
    elseif (isset($_REQUEST['anotherpost'])) {
        print $_REQUEST['anotherpost'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I try to pass the data `$_REQUEST['post']` return to argument and call `$_REQUEST['post']` in the else if but it didnt work

Comment: @user2118534: What exactly are you trying to do?